# Run PHP on an asp.net server

Tags: php, asp.net

I'm making a small questionnaire for a client and I had planned on using PHP. However the client has said that their servers are in asp.net so the PHP code won't work.

I've never came across this issue before and have never had an issue with PHP running on a web server. Is the client just mis-informed or will PHP not work on his server at all?

Sadly I don't have access to their server to test anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET apps are typically hosted by IIS on a windows server. [IIS supports running PHP applications](http://php.iis.net/).

Also, if it's IIS6, [that's supported as well](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/).

You may have problems if you can't get to the server and set it up, though.

Comment: So basically there shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: I just updated my answer, there is some setup involved. So either you need to do it, or they need to set it up. I know some companies are very strict about what can be installed on servers, and they maybe one of those companies. Just be sure they know what they're going to have to do, and make sure they're ok with it.

Comment: Definitely possible, I once (as an experiment I hasten to add) even got .asp suffixed addresses to pass the php parser as well as the asp - having said that it was "classic asp".

Answer (score 2):

I suppose what your client meant to say was there servers only support typical windows environment that doesn't comes with pre-installed PHP. to understand it more clearly let me put it this way

PHP and ASP are Server side scripting language, and IIS or Apache are Web Servers that understands your request and acts accordingly. a web server and a Server side scripting language are totally two different thing, although mostly people use Apache with PHP and, IIS with ASP doesn't necessarily means the web servers are limited to one language, hence Apache can be used with ASP and IIS with PHP it is the matter of your choice.

if you would like to run PHP in your windows server here is what you should be doing. 
[how to install php in iis 7](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&biw=1280&bih=638&q=how+to+install+php+in+iis+7&oq=how+to+install+php+in+iis&aq=0&aqi=g4g-v3g-j3&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=13310l20920l0l25l18l0l2l2l6l1931l10667l0.3.1.2.2.2.2.3.1&fp=3b2766c32387c3d7)

Comment: I didn't know apache could run asp?

Comment: yes you can run asp on apache. have a look at the link  http://www.apache-asp.org/

Comment: It's also possible to run ASP.NET applications though Apache, on Linux, http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET With FastCGI, the possibilities are really endless.